# How to call Spring cloud eureka service in TIBCO BE and BW. Is it posible?

Tags: netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, tibco-business-works, tibco-businessconnect

I want to call Spring cloud eureka application from TIBCO BE and BW for registering the tibco applications in Eureka service registry.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If you're running TIBCO BusinessWorks Container Edition, you can easily connect to Spring Cloud services by setting a few environment variables. The [documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/bwce/2.4.3/doc/html/GUID-2EA0B372-8363-4A6A-B712-C2B709A7B0F8.html) on the TIBCO Docs website will explain which variables you need to set, depending on where you're running your apps (either CloudFoundry or Docker based). Specifically for CloudFoundry based environments, there are [samples](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/bwce/2.4.3/doc/html/GUID-464ABE82-B01B-4936-A3DA-B824E59DA397.html) that will help guide you through deploying apps.

For the HTTP Connector you can refer to [this](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/bwce/2.4.3/doc/html/GUID-E7A7A6BD-20C7-496D-9F75-868B6F82FD1E.html) doc page on how and what to set.